# React native circle effect instagram stories

Tags: javascript, react-native, animation, instagram, react-animated

[image]

I would like to try to realize the effect that you see in the image gif, I thought to base myself on the following module to realize the circle:
[react-native-conical-gradient-progress](https://github.com/MikePodgorniy/react-native-conical-gradient-progress)

I'm having some trouble thinking about how to make it happen.

The problem is how to transform the whole circle, even portions of it into portions of semi-broken lines.

I do not know how to explain it better.

Can anyone give me some suggestions on what path I could follow?

Comment: This is definitely too broad for StackOverflow. You will have to do that yourself though. It does not look too complicated, but you will need to implement a custom implementation for that (animation, rendering).

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot: I would like to hear some opinions to try to determine what could be an ideal solution, considering the fact that a complex animation could take many fps and slow down the module a lot.
I did not ask to do it for me, I would not like this message.
In my opinion recreating such a thing is very complex if it is supposed that the intezione and to create it totally in js and not occupy too much space in cache for the animation.

Comment: That is not a complex animation at all. Instagram is made with React Native so I guess there is no issue with that.

Comment: @sfratini: We do not really know which parts are written entirely in native js / react and which instead use native Android / IOS modules.

Comment: Check the Airbnb module Lottie